# Adding microsoft sign in to android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, outlook, email

I am relatively new to Android Studio, but I need my app to have access to Microsoft (outlook, onedrive, etc) credentials.

I have tried to look up how to do this but only get results for adding Google sign-in, not Microsoft.

Is it just not possible to integrate Microsoft with Android Studio, or is there some way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the LiveSDK. Start here.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn631821.aspx

Yikes. This is more complicated than I originally thought. This page should help.

https://cuteprogramming.wordpress.com/category/experience/windows-live-sdk/

Comment: Is there a way to integrate LiveSDK with Android Studio? Everything I'm finding says it is only made for Eclipse?

Comment: It does look like they only really support Eclipse, but you can import the project into Android Studio. See the link in the updated answer.